# Is it possible to place a vector (or font) icon in macOS status bar?

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui, swift5

I use Swift 5 and SwiftUI (if it matters) and I want to place a vector icon (or a font icon, which would be a better option for me) next to a text in a status bar.

I've found an example which makes, as I understand, creates a button and puts it in the status bar.

```
    self.statusBarItem = NSStatusBar.system.statusItem(withLength: CGFloat(NSStatusItem.variableLength))
    if let button = self.statusBarItem.button {
        button.image = NSImage(named: "Icon")
        button.title = "MyText"
        button.action = #selector(togglePopover(_:))
    }
```

But, as I understand, using a raster image isn't a good idea, because it's size may vary depending on many things. And, usually, I use font icons for such things, which works perfectly almost everywhere.

Or, probably, it is possible to insert a SwiftUI view into the status bar item?

Comment: Are you asking if you can use a vector AppIcon for your app or just a vector image asset?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I came up with this method:

I made a custom font which is inherited from the standard San Francisco font and includes necessary icons in the Unicode area, so now I'm able to type any text and necessary icons there. I used the Icomoon website to make a font.

Moreover, there are [a lot of icons embedded in San Francisco font](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/sf-symbols/overview/) which you can use without any additional work (you can just copy the symbol from the app and paste it to the "title" property of the button).

Answer (score 0):

Here is what Apple says on this

```
/*
 Custom views should not be set on a status item.
 The button property with a template image will allow proper styling of 
 the status item in various states and contexts and should be used instead.
 */
@property (nullable, strong) NSView *view API_DEPRECATED("Use the standard button property instead", macos(10.0,10.14));
```

If you still want this, then NSButton is a view, and you always can add subview to it with your custom content. However I would recommend to go official way.

Comment: Yes, I've seen this recommendation and decided to follow it.
Now I'm thinking about to make my own font, nested from the system default font ("San Francisco", as I understand) and adding my icons do some extended area.
But it also doesn't look like a good solution...